# Automatically advancing a bi-directional generator to the point of accepting a non-None value?

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

Suppose we write a very simple bi-directional generator in Python:

```
def share_of_total():
    s = 0
    new_num = 0
    while True:
        new_num = yield new_num / (s or 1)
        s += new_num

share_calculator = share_of_total()
next(share_calculator)  # Without this we get the TypeError

for num in [1, 2, 3]:
    print(share_calculator.send(num))
```

This generator just accepts a number and yields a float representing its share of the sum of all previously provided numbers.

We would ideally like to just use it immediately as follows:

```py
share_calculator = share_of_total()
print(share_calculator.send(num))
```

However, this causes `TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator`. All users of the `share_of_total()` must remember to execute `next(share_calculator)` before the generator is usable as intended.

Is there an elegant way to make `share_calculator` immediately usable - i.e. to be able to immediately call `share_calculator.send(num)` after creating `share_calculator`?

Answer (score 0):

You should prime the generator with `share_calculator.send(None)`

Wrap this in a function that creates the generator for you:

```
def get_share_calculator():
    def share_of_total():
        s = 0
        new_num = 0
        while True:
            new_num = yield new_num / (s or 1)
            s += new_num
    retval = share_total()
    retval.send(None)
    return retval

share_calculator = get_share_calculator()

for num in [1, 2, 3]:
    print(share_calculator.send(num))
```